# Converting char* to int and converting back to the same char array

Tags: c++, c

Basically, I am trying to increment the int value of `port`. This should be easy but I am a little stuck.

It compile fine, but I got this error when I run it:
 Access violation writing location 0x001f5834

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
#define TESTING "5002"
int main()
{
    char* port = TESTING;
    int portint;
    sscanf ( port, "%d", &portint );
    portint++;
    cout << portint << endl; // it works fine up to here, it prints 5003
    sprintf ( port, "%d", portint);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because "5002" creates a `const char[]` decaying to `const char*` which are read only. Do `char[] x = TESTING; char* port = x`;

Comment: Is there anyway around this? I have to use this line: char* port = TESTING;

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's a C question, this is C++ code.  Not a duplicate.  Or rather, we can find a better duplicate.

Comment: @Zan: same complaint as to Whoz

Comment: @BenVoigt: Although I'd say since his code is using almost all C, let's replace his cout with printf and relabel it C.

Comment: @Zan: No, no no.  It's still C++ since he's using a C++ compiler.  The C rules simply do not apply.  Even if you replace `std::cout` with `printf`, the correct tag is still `c++`, not `c`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Since C is incorporated into C++ by reference, most of the rules do apply.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I'm talking about this particular scenario.  Completely different rules apply to string literals in C++.  Also, no the C language isn't incorporated by reference.  Only functions from the C standard library.

Comment: @BenVoigt were it not for the tags on the question, I would not have linked it. (and will neither rescind my close-vote for said-same).

Comment: @BenVoigt: As far as I can tell, the rules are exactly the same up until c++11.

Comment: @Zan: C++98, C++03, and C++11 may have the same rules regarding narrow string literals as each other, but not the same as C89, C90, and C11.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'd be interested in finding out what you're thinking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145793/string-literal-differences-between-c-and-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, compiler treats string literals as immutable, and an attempt to modify the contents of one results in an access violation error at run time because these strings are put into code segment, and it's read only. In your case, TESTING is a string literal, you can't not change its values. Try:

```
 char port[] = "5002";
```

Meanwhile, the compiler should have warning on this: when you assign a const char* type to a char* type.

MS C++ compiler has a compiler option regards this: [Zc:strictStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write "5003" back into "5002". "5002" is a string literal and cannot be written to.

I'll try to find a good duplicate for this question, because it has been asked in many ways, many times.

Answer (score 0):

In your usage, "5002" becomes a static array of characters and as such can not be modified.  I believe K&R address this, but I don't have the book in front of me right now.  Behavior would be different if you had declared an array.

Comment: This is C++, so the relevant rule is the one which sets the type of a string literal to `const char[N]`.  It's a `const` object, and const objects cannot be modified.

Comment: Question was also tagged as "C".  Also, I think my english "static array of characters" compiles to "const char[N]".

Comment: And aren't you proud.  I would understand your insistence if I gave a code example that was wrong, but I don't see anything wrong with my english explanation, which I believe actually conveys a better explanation than just the correct line of code.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with your explanation.  I'm just giving a more technical version, for readers who want that.  (Although you are wrong to suggest looking at K&R for this)